# When / While + gerund

Tags: gerunds, when

I would like to ask about two things

1. Can both "while" and "when" be used with a gerund?
2. Which one sounds better: "While ordering" or "when ordering" ?

   - While ordering a taxi, reliability is very important
   - When ordering a taxi, reliability is very important
   - When you order a taxi, reliability is very important

Comment: Both can be used, but they have slightly different meanings.'

Comment: The examples are strange. If you mean 'When ordering a taxi, it is important to know how reliable the firm is', I'd use this version. // Ordering a taxi is here a punctive event (happening at a point, or what can be considered a point, in time), so 'while' is inappropriate. Contrast 'While ordering a taxi, I dropped my wallet down a grid' (here, the phoning has to be considered as an extended period, with the mishap now the punctive event).

Comment: Ok, correct me if I`m wrong but is what you are saying essentially that "while" should be used with verbs in their non-punctive meaning? Like "While building a house [extended time period / building seen as a process] many unfortunate events happened" On the contrary, using "when" calls for a verb in its punctive meaning. Like "When building a house [building seen as point in time, as a whole], many unfortunate accidents may happen". Am I following you here?

Comment: Are these gerunds?  What year (approx) and whose inspiration changed them from being participles? Please.

Comment: @Hugh Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @Hugh I guess these are indeed participles, not gerunds. My bad. See, the thing is, you are probably an English native speaker. I am not. I am Polish and trying to master another language that is very very different from my native tongue. That`s why I come here and seek  help. If you find energy to throw in sarcastic comments, not  helpful ones, then this is not a place for you. .

Comment: No, no. Not sarcastic at all, but grievously out of date.   Before ordering a taxi, and after ordering a taxi the noun-verb follows a preposition and is a gerund.  Waiting for a taxi, patience is needed. Or Waiting for a taxi I dropped my wallet, are I think both participles, even though the qualified noun is only explicit in the second.  I genuinely don't know if conjunctions are currently treated as adverbs qualifying verbal adjectives (ptc) or are now sometimes categorised as prepositions taking objects (ger). I hope you and I find out

Comment: @IGO Also E A's remarks are still true about momentary and extended events. "While ordering a taxi, patience is very important." "When ordering a taxi, its reliability is very important."   These are both grammatical, but elliptical.

Comment: Ordering here is an example of a continuous ( an ongoing action). A gerund is a verb used as a noun and as such can be the subject or object in a phrase, which is not the case here. You can check this by changing the phrase thus: "When you are ordering a taxi..." etc. When you have a phrase with a gerund, you can't do this: "Ordering a taxi is a chore."

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hugh is quite right to question the taxonomy here as gerunds.  Rather, they should be treated as dangling participles (no subject for "ordering") or as a strained ellipsis ("When [one is] ordering a taxi, etc.").

As for the difference between "when" and "while, I'd say that depends very much on context.  If the statement is "gnomic" (i.e., trying to offer a generalization), the "when" connective is appropriate;  but if the statement is circumstantial (that is, two acts will be directly correlated by time), "while" serves well.

Answer (score 0):

I think "when ordering" is equivalent to "if ordering" -- "when" indicates only that in this context, multiple concepts or facts coexist.

In contrast, "while ordering" implies that a second activity will take place concurrently, as in, "while ordering he could not help but stare at her nose".